# What is the class equivalent of functools.partial(func,myArgs)?

Tags: python

I am using partial to add myArgs to my function calls. but calculating the value of myArgs requires reading it from a file.
I would like to convert the partial decorator to a class.
How can I do it?

```
class withHostAndToken(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.HOST = ''
        self.TOKEN = ''


    def __call__(self, func):

        if self.HOST == '':
            self.HOST = cfg.getHost()
        if self.TOKEN == '':
            self.TOKEN == cfg.getToken()

        return functools.partial( func , self.HOST, self.TOKEN)
```

The error I am getting is:

> return functools.partial( func , self.HOST, self.TOKEN)  TypeError:
>   the first argument must be callable

Here is the none class version of this:

```
def withHostAndToken(func):
    HOST = cfg.getHost()
    TOKEN = cfg.getToken()
    return functools.partial(func , HOST, TOKEN)
```

and this works with:

```
@withHostAndToken
def myFunction(HOST, TOKEN, other_arg):
    '''do something'''

myFunction(other_arg='someValue')
```

Comment: I started to answer to this but ... couldn't. Can you post the example on how you expect this to be used and how'd you use `functools.partial`?

Comment: What is `func`, looks like it isn't a function? And why do you pass it to `__init__()` and `__call__()`

Comment: agreed. What is `func` here?

Comment: because partial expect to get a func as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your decorator logic backwards, you get the `func` in `__init__` (as you aren't defining a decorator with arguments). You would get any args to your `func` in `__call__`, e.g.:

```
class withHostAndToken(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = functools.partial(func, HOST=cfg.getHost(), TOKEN=cfg.getToken())    

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Though you don't need `functools.partial`, e.g.:

```
class withHostAndToken(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.HOST = cfg.getHost()
        self.TOKEN = cfg.getToken()  

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self.HOST, self.TOKEN, *args, **kwargs)
```

*Note: not sure where you are getting `cfg` from, assuming a global variable.*

Comment: But what if func get other parameters like: 
`def withHostAndToken(func):
        HOST = cfg.getHost()
        TOKEN = cfg.getToken()
        return functools.partial(func , HOST, TOKEN)

and this works with:

    @withHostAndToken
    def myFunction(HOST, TOKEN, other_arg):
        '''do something'''

    myFunction(other_arg='someValue')`

Comment: Just pass the `*args, **kwargs` to your downstream function.

Comment: Got extra parenthesis in `__init__` at `cfg.getToken())`. I can't edit because it's too small of a change.

Comment: Should have mentioned it's in the second example :)